# Flutter widget dynamically on top of the rest

Tags: listview, flutter

This is a question about changing the rendering order in Flutter.

I have a ListView with zoomable images. I need that when the user pans the image scales and is rendered over the other images.

My current implementation is covering images that preceding in the list the scaled one. For the following ones, it is rendered underneath.

If it helps, I'm trying to achieve the same zoom effect the Instagram app has.

Any idea how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at overlays. Fluttery does a great job explaining them https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xm0ELlBtNWM

Comment: @Sebastian awesome thanks!